# Having trouble achieving queries and cascading deletes using EF Core 7 conventions with a bridge table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-core

In my SQL database, I have a `Units` table. I also have a `Containers` table. Units can have Containers, and that relationship is established with a `UnitContainers` table, which contains a ContainerId - a foreign key to the ContainerId column of the Containers table; and a UnitId, which is a foreign key back to the UnitId on the Units table. The reason for the UnitId not being directly on the Containers table is because Containers can also belong to other types of entities, so it was decided to have a bridge table for each type rather than to change the table definition every time we wanted to associate a new type with Containers.

In OnModelCreating(), currently I have the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UnitContainer>().HasKey(uc => new { uc.UnitId, uc.ContainerId });

modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UnitContainers)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UnitId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Container>()
            .HasMany(c => c.UnitContainers)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.ContainerId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UnitContainer>()
            .HasKey(uc => new { uc.UnitId, uc.ContainerId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UnitContainer>()
            .HasOne(uc => uc.Unit)
            .WithMany(u => u.UnitContainers)
            .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UnitId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UnitContainer>()
            .HasOne(uc => uc.Container)
            .WithMany(c => c.UnitContainers)
            .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.ContainerId);
```

I've tried several other permutations of the configuration but they all pretty much result in the same thing, and that is, when I go to execute this linq query:

```
var query = ctx.Set<Unit>()
            .Include(unit => unit.Containers);
```

I get a SqlException:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column
> name 'UnitId'. Invalid column name 'UnitId'.

This is because the generated SQL is trying to LEFT JOIN Containers to Units directly, rather than using the UnitContainers bridge table.

Consider this part one of my question. Part two is not only do I need this to work, I also need cascading deletes to work so that when I delete a Unit, any entries referencing that Unit in UnitContainers also gets deleted.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my configuration?

Here is the Unit entity:

```
public class Unit
{
    [Key]
    UnitId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UnitContainer> UnitContainers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Container> Containers { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the Container entity:

```
public class Container
{
    [Key]
    public int ContainerId { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    public Unit Unit { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UnitContainer> UnitContainers { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Many-To-Many mapping with code-first](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First)

Comment: I couldn't get it working with cascade deletes. Ended up just doing them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've configured the `UnitConfigurations` property relationship multiple times.
In this one...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UnitContainers)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UnitId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

You declared a one sided relationship, `Unit` has a `UnitContainers` collection, but `UnitConfiguration` is not aware of the relationship initiated from `Unit` ... `.WithOne()`

Then you declared a relationship for property `UnitContainers` again...

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<UnitContainer>()
            .HasOne(uc => uc.Unit)
            .WithMany(u => u.UnitContainers)
            .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UnitId);
```

This time, there is a reciprocal relationship `.HasOne(uc=>uc.Unit)`  Both of these are configuring the same relationship and both configure the `UnitContainers` property.  However, two different relationships between the same entities cannot share the same key.

Either leave both `With` clauses empty,...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UnitContainers)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UnitId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
modelBuilder.Entity<UnitContainer>()
            .HasOne(uc => uc.Unit)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UnitId);
```

or get rid of the `Unit` relationship and use the `UnitConfiguration` as already defined.

As a bonus...
If you want to skip the intermediate navigation for `UnitConfiguration`, for example navigation directly to `List<Configuration> Configurations` from `Unit` or vice verse, you can try the following configuration:

```
modelbuilder.Entity<Unit>
   .HasMany(x=>x.Configurations)
   .WithMany()
   .UsingEntity<UnitConfiguration>();
```